# Something wrong about print function in doneFunction (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, printing

i try to print page after columnize function is finished but print function is happen 2 times ,First time it print before columnize function is done and second time it's happen when columnize function is finished.Can you help me ?

this is my code

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        var content_height = 856;   // the height of the content, discluding the header/footer
        var page = 1;               // the beginning page number to show in the footer
        function buildNewsletter() {
            if ($('#newsletterContent').contents().length > 0) {
                // when we need to add a new page, use a jq object for a template
                // or use a long HTML string, whatever your preference
                $page = $("#page_template").clone().addClass("page").css("display", "block");

                // fun stuff, like adding page numbers to the footer
                $page.find(".footer #lbl_pageNum").append(page);
                $page.find(".footer #lbl_pageNum2").append(page);
                //create label to recive data

                $("body").append($page);
                page++;

                // here is the columnizer magic
                $('#newsletterContent').columnize({
                    columns: 1,
                    target: ".page:last .content",
                    overflow: {
                        height: content_height,
                        id: "#newsletterContent",
                        doneFunc: function () {
                            console.log("done with page");
                            buildNewsletter();                                
                            printForm();                                
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        setTimeout(buildNewsletter, 1000);            
    });
    function printForm() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The function `buildNewsletter` is recursive. You call it in the `doneFunc` of `columnize()` again. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: I try to put printForm out of doneFunc() but it's still happen before columnize is finish. Can u help me please?